# Stop iPhone from sending iMessages to OS X

Tags: macos, iphone, messages

I recently got an iMac and I set up that my photos and music from my iMac get downloaded to my iPhone.

But now my messages on my iPhone are getting sent to my iMac. I went on my iPhone and clicked Settings > Messages > Send and Recieve but it doesn't show an email that is set up to my Mac. I also can't find preferences for messages on my Mac. How do I stop iMessages from my Phone going to my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Messages on your Mac, open Preferences (in the menu bar, it's Messages > Preferences), click on Accounts, click on your Apple ID in the list of messaging accounts, and uncheck "Enable this account."